# If statement in function error

Tags: r

How can I fork if a function gives me an error?
In C I used to attach it to the if statement(i.e scanf if succeed returns a 1 otherwise 0)

But here doesn't work here is the example:

```
if((htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE)))
{
    #DO
}else #DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

Comment: Is `tryCatch` what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm more interested in a TRUE/FALSE response instead of a custom message

Answer (score 0):

Found

```
if(class(try(htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE), silent=T))!="try-error")
```